# Realistic lighting (sunlight) with Three.js?

Tags: three.js, lighting

I'm attempting to create a small 1st-person game using Three.js, but I'm having trouble with the lighting. Basically I want to simulate the sun and have it rotate around casting light on everything. I'm using `THREE.DirectionalLight` at the moment and it only lights up the one direction so sides of cubes remain black/dark.

Do I have to use multiple lights so everything is lit up? Or could I somehow reflect light off the ground/objects?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, you'll have to use multiple lights to achieve this, faking the reflected light. Computing real reflected light isn't built in (and computationally very complex/expensive). You have a variety of options.

A second directional light that could always be in the opposite position and direction of your sun.

A hemisphere light that remains constant. Hemisphere lighting gets a sky color and a ground color and intensity and adds a nice extra bit of depth to your lighting.

```
//                                    sky color ground color intensity 
hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0.6 );
```

here's a working example https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_lights_hemisphere

you could use any combination of different lights but be careful there's a performance trade off.

It's also worth mentioning half-lambert shading which is enabled by setting the wrapAround property to true in your material. This gives a nicer falloff to black that results in less harsh lighting. More mid tones and less blacks.

Comment: Thanks! Setting wrapAround to true has fixed it. Now there's no blacks and the colors are still visible even when not directly in the light, which was what I wanted. I've updated the original link :) Just need to figure out how to fix my shadow problem now.

Comment: wrapAround seems to have been removed since this comment was posted. How can this effect be achieved now?

Answer (score 22):

I used a combination of these two lights to create this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m68FDmU0wGw

```
            var hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0.6 );
            hemiLight.color.setHSV( 0.6, 0.75, 0.5 );
            hemiLight.groundColor.setHSV( 0.095, 0.5, 0.5 );
            hemiLight.position.set( 0, 500, 0 );
            scene.add( hemiLight );

            var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
            dirLight.position.set( -1, 0.75, 1 );
            dirLight.position.multiplyScalar( 50);
            dirLight.name = "dirlight";
            // dirLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;

            scene.add( dirLight );

            dirLight.castShadow = true;
            dirLight.shadowMapWidth = dirLight.shadowMapHeight = 1024*2;

            var d = 300;

            dirLight.shadowCameraLeft = -d;
            dirLight.shadowCameraRight = d;
            dirLight.shadowCameraTop = d;
            dirLight.shadowCameraBottom = -d;

            dirLight.shadowCameraFar = 3500;
            dirLight.shadowBias = -0.0001;
            dirLight.shadowDarkness = 0.35;
```

Comment: this is great. Is the source code available anywhere?

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately. I intended to open it, but simply didn't find the time. I can dig this out, if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use scene.environment to do this job, there is already a good example here:

https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/

check gltf-viewer's code here, which did a great job in sunlight.

https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-gltf-viewer/blob/main/src/viewer.js

notice the environments vairable, which use venice_sunset_1k.hdr as their default background.

To be more detailed, they use a background as their environment, but they didn't 'show' them, you can use the code below

```
    this.pmremGenerator = new PMREMGenerator( this.renderer );
    this.pmremGenerator.compileEquirectangularShader();
    var rgbe_loader = new RGBELoader();
    var that = this;
    rgbe_loader.setDataType(UnsignedByteType).load("/environment/venice_sunset_2k.hdr", function(texture) {

        var envMap = that.pmremGenerator.fromEquirectangular(texture).texture;

        that.scene.environment = envMap;

        texture.dispose();
        that.pmremGenerator.dispose();

    });
```

where the hdr file can be found in https://polyhaven.com/a/venice_sunset