# How to view Intrinsic color of an STL file using three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a binary STL colored file. I can see the color using the online mesh viewer http://www.viewstl.com/.

I am using the below standard approach to load and visualize the stl file, and it works well. However, the **intrisic colors** do not appear correctly and are too sensivite to light changes.

```
Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
scene = new THREE.Scene();
var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
var d = 100;
camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( - d * aspect, d, d * aspect,- d, 1, 1000 );
camera.position.set( 0, 0, 200 );
camera.lookAt( scene.position ); 
scene.add( camera );
var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 ); // soft white light
scene.add( light );
var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
directionalLight.position.x = 0; 
directionalLight.position.y = 0; 
directionalLight.position.z = 1; 
directionalLight.position.normalize();
scene.add( directionalLight );
var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xAAAAAA, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 0 } );
// Colored binary STL

var stlfile = "myBinarySTLColoredFile.stl"
loader.load( stlfile, function ( geometry ) {
    var meshMaterial = material;
    if (geometry.hasColors) {
        meshMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ opacity: geometry.alpha, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors });
    }
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, meshMaterial );
scene.add( 
mesh.position.set(-100, -100, 0);
});

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true,  antialias: true } ); 
renderer.setSize(....);

var container = document.getElementById('`enter code here`flex2');
```

***Question: How to visualize the color enclosed in the STL file ?***

Thanks

Comment: Hi, i am working on a project which need to display STL files on browser, but currently i have no idea of how to do this. could you please give me some suggestion? if you could provide me a working demo, it will be great. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally succeed to render correctly the colored object.

**I use PLYLoader instead of STLLoader.**

Apparently, three.js STL api do not manage the color.

Answer (score 1):

There is no right answer. The color will depend on the light.
See the clear thread [Realistic lighting (sunlight) with Three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478093/realistic-lighting-sunlight-with-three-js)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but for anyone else who comes across it, I don't think the accepted answer about using the `PLYLoader` instead of the `STLLloader` is correct, the `STLLoader` appears to support embedded color in binary `STL`s just fine in the [example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_stl.html).

One possible cause of the OP's issue using `THREE.VertexColors` in `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ opacity: geometry.alpha, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors })` instead of `true` as in the [docs/example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_stl.html#L119).

Answer (score 0):

To get the original colors and no directional lighting, remove the directional light and crank the ambient light up to full brightness:

```
...
scene.add( camera );

var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xFFFFFF ); // Full-bright white light
scene.add( light );

var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
...
```

If that doesn't give you the desired result, please add screenshots of the actual and desired visual look to your question.

Comment: Thank you. It does not work.  I have a full white statue.